# How do I place an image after a link?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

I need to have a link in my webpage followed by a question mark image, so that a mouse over on the question mark image, shows a tool tip. This is the code I have:

```
 <p>
  <a class="mainLinks" href="#">Currency Converter</a><a href="#" class="questionIcon">&nbsp;</a>
 </p>
```

and the corresponding css is:

```
 .costSummaryBox .questionIcon{
       background:url(../images/static/question2.png) no-repeat;
       text-decoration:none;
}
```

But in my webpage, I get the image below the link. How do I make them appear in the same line?

Comment: Try setting float:left inside the class.

Comment: why not use an image followed by an anchor and use its title attribute to set the tool tip?

Comment: You need to widen the width of parent tag of your anchor.....

Comment: @ ashish: Setting float:left didn't work.

Comment: @ asgs:That I do, But I need another link before that Image.

Comment: Can we have access to the webpage you are referring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<p>
   <a class="mainLinks" href="#">Currency Converter&nbsp;<img src="../images/static/question2.png" /></a>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I get both in the same line :)

Comment: By the way, the `&nbsp;` between text and image has no effect. If you want non-breakability between these two elements, you have to wrap an element with CSS `white-space:nowrap` around them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AFTER. This link might help:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/sel_after.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<p>
    <a class="mainLinks" href="#">Currency Converter</a>
</p>

.mainLinks{
    padding-right:30px;
    background:#fff url(...) no-repeat right top;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/eMLkS/